# Troubleshooting cudf.tokenize(): 'Length Mismatch' error with non-space delimiters

Tags: python, rapids, cudf

Cudf Tokenize Element Length Mismatch

This is the expected result for tokenize(' ') on space character:

```
0                     Due
0                      to
0                   being
0                      on
0                    FMLA
               ...       
23956              copies
23956                  of
23956                 the
23956            original
23956    message.\r\n\r\n
Name: description, Length: 3520739, dtype: object
```

This is the result of tokenize('b') on a character with lower occurrence than space:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 57
     52 desc = cudf.Series.from_pandas(df.description)
     56 desc.str.normalize_characters()
---> 57 desc.str.tokenize('b')
     58 #sr = sr.str.normalize_characters()
     59 #sr.str.tokenize(res)

File ~/base-env/envs/workenvs/envs/workdir/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cudf/core/column/string.py:4592, in StringMethods.tokenize(self, delimiter)
   4587     raise TypeError(
   4588         f"Expected a Scalar or Column\
   4589         for delimiters, but got {type(delimiter)}"
   4590     )
   4591 if isinstance(self._parent, cudf.Series):
-> 4592     result.index = self._parent.index.repeat(  # type: ignore
   4593         self.token_count()
   4594     )
   4595 return result

File ~/base-env/envs/workenvs/envs/workdir/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cudf/core/indexed_frame.py:528, in IndexedFrame.index(self, value)
    526 # A DataFrame with 0 columns can have an index of arbitrary length.
    527 if len(self._data) > 0 and new_length != old_length:
--> 528     raise ValueError(
    529         f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_length} elements, "
    530         f"new values have {len(value)} elements"
    531     )
    532 self._index = Index(value)

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 292122 elements, new values have 3520739 elements
```

this is the result of tokenize('a') on a character with higher occurrence than space:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 57
     52 desc = cudf.Series.from_pandas(df.description)
     56 desc.str.normalize_characters()
---> 57 desc.str.tokenize('a')
     58 #sr = sr.str.normalize_characters()
     59 #sr.str.tokenize(res)

File ~/base-env/envs/workenvs/envs/workdir/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cudf/core/column/string.py:4592, in StringMethods.tokenize(self, delimiter)
   4587     raise TypeError(
   4588         f"Expected a Scalar or Column\
   4589         for delimiters, but got {type(delimiter)}"
   4590     )
   4591 if isinstance(self._parent, cudf.Series):
-> 4592     result.index = self._parent.index.repeat(  # type: ignore
   4593         self.token_count()
   4594     )
   4595 return result

File ~/base-env/envs/workenvs/envs/workdir/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cudf/core/indexed_frame.py:528, in IndexedFrame.index(self, value)
    526 # A DataFrame with 0 columns can have an index of arbitrary length.
    527 if len(self._data) > 0 and new_length != old_length:
--> 528     raise ValueError(
    529         f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_length} elements, "
    530         f"new values have {len(value)} elements"
    531     )
    532 self._index = Index(value)

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1991581 elements, new values have 3520739 elements
```

I feel like it is pre-predicting the elements size based on space.

Answer (score 0):

Documented bug resolved in future release: cuDF 23.06

https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/7766#issue-845284841

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).